# How can run GWT with google app engine application in Production Mode don't need Deploy to App Engine

Tags: gwt

Can I run my app (GWT with google app engine ) in Production Mode on my computer ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/usingeclipse#compiling seen can not run on local?

Answer (score 1):

Compile your project and then launch the DevMode, but simply don't put the `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` bit in the URL.